# Is conversion from one colour profile to another clearly defined

Tags: color-management, color-spaces

Is conversion from one colour profile to the other other clearly defined ?

If I change the ICC profile for an image from sRGB to another profile such as Adobe RGB will it be applied the same way by all Imaging software ?

Will it be applied the same way if the printer converts the profile to one based on the CMYK Colour Space such as FOGRA27 profile as if I convert it to a FOGRA27 profile myself before sending to the printer ?

(I think that with softproofing the image can be modified as well but with just changing the profile we are just changing the mapping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusion color model and color space. sRGB and AdobeRGB are the same color model (RGB) but are different color spaces. CMYK is a different model and in itself does *not* define a color-space.

The transformation between sRGB and AdobeRGB is therefore more similar but software still have leeway on how to apply it. Any color outside sRGB can be mapped differently, some software offer users options which different properties, some preserve the input as much as possible while other transform so that colors are relatively proportional. See [this link](http://www.color-management-guide.com/conversion-mode-perceptual-relative-colorimetric-rendering-intent.html) for an explanation.

Comment: Ive fixed the question regarding colour profiles and spaces

Comment: Ah useful link but I think this is the one I needed http://www.color-management-guide.com/convert-to-profile-an-image.html I thought when you changed colour profile the RGB values didn't change but just how they mapped to LAB changed. Whereas actaully if you have the right profile to start with and then change to another profile it goes RGB - > LAB and then LAB -> new RGB and the problems arise when original RGB maps to a particular LAB value, and that LAB value isn't mapped to by RGB in the colour space, which is where they have some leeway.

Comment: But I dont see you can use perceptual/relative except when soft proofing. Because for example if I export a image as a jpeg in Lightroom I can specify the embedded profile but I don't specify how it is done, or does it literally just change the profile without actually converting the rgb vales from rgb -> lab > newrgb when I pick this option. To put it another way can I properly convert image from one profile to another at export stage or it only to be used to correctly specified the right profile in case it is currently set wrong.

Comment: Not 100% sure about LR but IIRC, it just converts without asking, so what choice it does is fixed. In theory you can and there are plenty of mappings possible. If you embed the color-profile, then it does not have to change values, otherwise, it has no choice but to produce pixels of certain values according to the mapping it uses.

Comment: sorry I dont understand what you are saying

Comment: OK, let me simplify. When embedding the profile, one does not need to transform pixels, only the viewer does. Without a profile, the only choice is doing the transformation to a known common profile which is usually sRGB. Having the viewer do the transform allows to compose mappings and reduce artifacts in the process since another mapping might be needed to get pixels in the display or print color-space.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think youre saying that Lightroom always has the raw image and can therefore ensure we dont lose information if we have to do multiple mappings ? But that is all well and good but at some point I need to export an image that can be used and printed outside of Lightroom, so Im expecting the exported image to use the profile required for printing and therefore wont it now have different pixel values because different models would have different rgb values mapping to the same LAB value( or equiv CMYK value if a CMYK based profile for printing)

Comment: Unless you export a TIFF, you won't be able to have a CMYK file. It will be RGB with a color-space attached to describe what these values mean. It will be the responsibility of the printer software to use the RGB value and profile together to perform the conversion. If you want to RGB values to be of a specific profile (most commonly sRGB) then some application can output a JPEG like that without color-profile, so it is the responsibility of the application to interpret it correctly.

Comment: Okay so Im now using Lightroom6 which lets me soft proof to a CMYK profile and I can see that neither sRGB and CMYK can accurately map many pixels for certain images, the ProPhoto profile does. But Lightoom doesnt allow me to specify a CMYK profile when exporting even when I use TIFF so Im thinking export with ProPhoto rather than sRGB so no mapping problem at that point, so we only get mapping adjustments when printer converts to FOGRA but then we have no choice over whether they do perpetual or relative conversion, I cant see how to get round that.

Answer (score 0):

There are four rendering options for converting color spaces. Two are of interest to photographers. These options instruct the software how to deal with out of gamut colors. Once an images is rendered to a smaller color space you can go back to a larger colors space but you cannot undo the rendering to get the same picture back.